# Naming error in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join

I get this error when trying to create a record in my joins table

> NameError in
>   SubscriptionsController#new
>
> uninitialized constant
>   Channel::ChannelsUser

Subscriptions Controller

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController

  helper_method :current_user_session, :current_user
  filter_parameter_logging :password, :password_confirmation

  def new
    @channel = Channel.find(params[:channel_id])
    @user = current_user
    @channel.subscribers << @user
    @channel.save
    flash[:notice] = "You have subscribed to: " +@channel.name
    redirect_to @channel
  end

end
```

end

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_authentic

  ROLES = %w[admin  moderator subscriber]

  #Each user can subscribe to many channels
  has_many :channels_users
  has_many :subscriptions, :class_name => "Channel", :through => :channels_users

  #Each user who is a moderator can moderate many channels
  has_many :channel_mods
  has_many :channels, :through => :channel_mods

  #Each user can receive many messages
  has_many :messages_users , :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :reciepts , :class_name => "User", :through => :messages_users

  #Filter users by role(s)
  named_scope :with_role, lambda { |role| {:conditions => "roles_mask & #{2**ROLES.index(role.to_s)} > 0 "} }

  def roles  
    ROLES.reject { |r| ((roles_mask || 0) & 2**ROLES.index(r)).zero? }  
  end

  def roles=(roles)  
    self.roles_mask = (roles & ROLES).map { |r| 2**ROLES.index(r) }.sum  
  end

  def role_symbols
    role.map do |role|
      role.name.underscore.to_sym
    end
  end

end
```

Channel Model

```
class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
  #Each channel owns many or no messages
  has_many :messages
  #Each channel is own by one moderator
  has_many :channel_mods
  has_many :moderators, :class_name =>'User', :through =>:channel_mod
  #Each channel can have and belong to many or no users
  has_many :channels_users
  has_many :subscribers, :class_name => 'Users' , :through => :channels_users

end
```

ChannelsUsers model

```
class ChannelsUsers < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :channel
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would read much nicer if you change the model to ChannelUser.  Here are the corresponding relationships:

```
class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :channel_users
  has_many :users, :through => :channel_users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :channel_users
  has_many :channels, :through => :channel_users
end

class ChannelUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :channel
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Your join table would then be called `channel_users`.  I think you named it `channels_users` initially because that's the setup for a has_and_belongs_to_many join table.  But since you're using `has_many :through`, you're free to name the table as you like.

I wrote a blog article earlier this year that walks through all the options in detail:

[Basic Many-to-Many Associations in Rails](http://kconrails.com/2010/01/29/has_and_belongs_to_many-associations-in-ruby-on-rails)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Did it your way now its uninitialized constant Channel::ChannelUser

Comment: Couldn't get with has_many :through but has_and_belongs_to_many worked for me thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your channel user class name is a plural. It is supposed to be singular.

So either you can change to this:

```
class ChannelsUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :channel
end
```

or change this line in `User` and `Channel` model:

```
has_many :channels_users
```

to

```
has_many :channels_users, :class_name => 'ChannelsUsers'
```

Rails will use the methods like `String#classify` and `String#underscore` to detect classes and relationships.

If you want to play around with the names, in the console try out various combinations:

```
>> "channels_users".classify
=> "ChannelsUser"
>> "ChannelsUser".underscore
=> "channels_user"
```

Comment: I tried doing it the second way, but no progress if do it the first way do I have to regenerate the file is so how? the first time I did rails g model ChannelsUsers

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the answer. It should have been `:class_name => 'ChannelUsers'`. I have edited the answer.

Comment: now i get this error,   Could not find the source association(s) :subscriber or :subscribers in model ChannelsUsers.

Comment: I fixed that with has_many :subscribers, :class_name => 'Users' , :through => :channels_users , :source => :user.   But now unitilized constant Channel::Users is the error